# HTML semantico e uso do css3

Tags: html5, css3

As tags html de italico, sublinhado e negrito devem deixar de ser usadas e esses efeitos textuais-visuais devem ficar a cargo do css3? Com essa onda de html semantico fiquei com essa duvida.

Comment: A quais tags você se refere exatamente? `<b>` e `<i>`?

Comment: A sua pergunta está pouco clara. Poderia editá-la adicionando um pouco mais de detalhes?

Comment: A semântica é toda feita no HTML, não no CSS. Na verdade não existe nada que vc faz no CSS que afeta a semântica das coisas, mesmo elementos com display:none, em alguns casos são lidos por leitores de tela, então não há nada que vc possa fazer no CSS para melhorar semântica, na verdade o pessoal costuma é atrapalhar a a cessibilidade pelo CSS, colocando cores sem contraste, fonte pequenas e removendo outline. De mais detalhes na sua pergunta, a forma como perguntou ficou um pouco vaga.

Answer (score 1):

O HTML semântico veio com o HTML5, que possibilitou o uso de novas tags, como por exemplo as tags **header**, **main** e **footer**. Para mostrar a relevância de um trecho do texto dentro de um conteúdo, pode-se usar a tag **em** ou **strong**. Visualmente, se usar a tag **b** terá o mesmo efeito para quem está visualizando o site, mas a interpretação de um leitor de tela (programa que lê o o que está em um site para deficientes visuais) por exemplo se beneficiará com o HTML semântico, pois será capaz de identificar cada elemento. O mesmo acontece com os robôs do Google, sem um HTML semântico os robôs não conseguem identificar o menu de navegação, por exemplo, nem mesmo saber qual é o conteúdo principal do seu site.

CSS3, como pode ser encontrado na Wikipédia,

> "é a terceira mais nova versão das famosas Cascading Style Sheets (ou simplesmente CSS), onde se define estilos para seu projeto web.Com efeitos de transição, imagem,imagem de fundo/Background e outros, que dão um estilo novo e elegante a seus projetos web. Ou em todos os aspectos de design do layout da página.
>   A principal função do CSS3 é abolir as imagens de plano/Background de fundo, bordas arredondadas, apresentar transições e efeitos para criar animações de vários tipos, como um simples relógio de ponteiros."

Com isso, pode-se concluir que as tags de itálico, sublinhado e negrito devem continuar a ser usadas normalmente, devendo quando possível se fazer uso das tags semânticas.